# How do I charge a transaction in authorize.net CIM to a customerProfileId without using an existing paymentProfileId?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I can not find anywhere in the documentation where I can charge a credit card and associate it to an existing customer profile id without also having an existing customer payment profile id - in a single step.

Shouldn't I be able to simply charge a transaction against the customer profile without needing a payment profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the down votes, this may be useful to others. It seems counter intuitive that a payment profile is required prior to charging a new credit card to an existing customer. However, I have confirmed this is indeed the case.